# How can I see who is connecting to my websites on my server and possibly their IPs ?

Tags: server, traffic, ip-address

1) How can I know how many people is connected to the server in a specific moment (or previous hours of the day). (Even in real-time)

2) How can I know which one of the websites on my server they are visiting. (The websites are in different folders

3) How can I see their IPs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For web servers like [IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324279) & [Apache](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/configuring-web-logs-apache), you can configure website logging to track visitors. While setting it up, you can specify what details (like date/time, IP address of visitor, status of the request etc) you wish to capture. There are log file analyzer tools that you can then use to conveniently view desired details.

Alternatively, you can use one of the many [Web Analytics tools](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/04/comparison-of-free-web-analytics-tools.html) that are available to track visitors

Comment: Be aware that this IP will not always be the explicit user IP, they may be behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

[Netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) provides real-time IP connection information, but it will not tell you which website they are visiting. I use it all the time to check how many users are on the server before doing patches etc.

As for getting which website they are connected to, you would need to parse through the log files for that information or use a real time web analytic tool.

Answer (score 0):

To see the IPs of those who are connecting to your site, you can check the stats which is available via Awstats or Webalizer (if you are suing cPanel or Plesk).

You can also check your domain access_logs or ask the support department of your hosting provider to give you those logs.